# sizeof(void*) != sizeof(uintptr_t) in practice?

Tags: c, c99

While the C99 standard theoretically allows for `sizeof(void*) != sizeof(uintptr_t)` (at least as I understand it), are there any modern systems where the widths are different? i.e., as a practical matter, would it be reasonable to rely on the assumption that these types have the same width?

Comment: How would you even rely on that assumption? What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: The `intptr_t` (and `uintptr_t` of course) should be big enough to hold *any* pointer. At least on platforms where pointers are stored as integer values whose value is the address where the pointer is pointing. Which is just about all major and minor platforms and systems these days.

Comment: Why *would* you care about them being the same width?

Comment: I'd call that a fair bet, but put a `static_assert` in there just to be safe.

Comment: Context: ugly hack, see https://github.com/go-gl/gl/issues/71. Effectively I need a type that is exactly the same width as `void*` so I can change the typedef of `GLsync` from `typedef struct __GLsync *GLsync` to `typedef uintptr_t GLsync`. Necessary because Go does not allow non-pointer values in pointer types, but some drivers use that opaque struct to return numeric handles (e.g., "1").

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude [intptr_t (and uintptr_t of course) should be big enough to hold any pointer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44357802/sizeofvoid-sizeofuintptr-t-in-practice#comment75717681_44357802) better applies to _object_ pointers.  It is not uncommon to have _function pointers_ exceeding `uintptr_t` size.

Comment: I encountered a compiler, that if it had a uintptr_t (which afaik it did not) it would have to provide `sizeof(unitptr_t) != sizeof(const void *)`. This compiler was weird and `sizeof(const void *) != sizeof(void *)` and the size of said pointer was not equal to the size of any integer type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> the C99 standard theoretically allows for `sizeof(void*) != sizeof(uintptr_t)` are there any modern systems where the widths are different?

I know no such system today (but perhaps you might find some weird VLIW embedded microcontroller). 1990 era Cray was an exception (but it was C89, not C99).

> i.e., as a practical matter, would it be reasonable to rely on the assumption that these types have the same width?

Certainly **yes in *practice***. BTW, very often your source code would practically have other dependencies (e.g. typically uses some non- C99-standard function, but commonly available ones, like e.g. [POSIX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX)).

<sup>(in practice, strictly conforming C99 useful programs not depending upon external libraries are very rare)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

To add to [@Basile Starynkevitch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44358156/2410359) good answer:

`(u)intptr_t` are *optional* types.  Whereas `sizeof(void*) != sizeof(uintptr_t)` might be rare or non-existent, consider first establishing if `(u)intptr_t` exists.

> 7.20.1.4 Integer types capable of holding object pointers
> ...
> These types are optional.

```
#include <stdint.h>
#ifndef UINTPTR_MAX
#  error uintptr_t does not exist.
#endif
```